# Raspberry Pi 4B Not rebooting with NFS share

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, nfs, hang

I have my Pi running as both a DNS server using PiHole and twice a day collecting my saved PVR from iPlayer via a VPN. If there's anything downloaded then that's copied to a NFS share on my Synology NAS. i.e. my fstab on the Pi has these lines

```
aragorn:/volume1/Gimli_Backup /mnt/Gimli_Backup/ nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,nosuid,timeo=14,soft 0 0
aragorn:/volume1/Gimli_Iplayer /mnt/Gimli_Iplayer/ nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,nosuid,timeo=14,soft 0 0
aragorrn:"/volume1/Temp Storage"/ /mnt/Aragorn-Temp/ nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,nosuid,timeo=14,soft 0 0
```

I am sure this had worked but recently after a reboot the Pi did not recover. I thought I'd corrupted the memory card but using my very recent backup I got the same situation. Trying a brand new clean image it would boot.

Comment: If you are using systemd you can try adding `_netdev` to the options to make it wait for a network before mounting (man systemd.mount).

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I added back the mount points to fstab then it would hang again. I surmise it is waiting for the shares to mount before connecting the network so is perpetually stuck. My solution is to remove the mount from fstab and then call a script from cron 30 seconds after boot, a procedure I already use on my MINT desktop